# Error Terraforming Snowflake (Error: open snowflake connection: 260008 (08004): failed to connect to db. verify account name is correct. HTTP: 403)

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I can't connect to Snowflake via Terraform and I suspect it's because I changed my account details.

My `main.tf` file is

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    snowflake = {
      source  = "Snowflake-Labs/snowflake"
      version = "0.77.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "snowflake" {
  account   = "yzazxrk-pj50733"
  user      = "username"
  password  = "password"
  role      = "ACCOUNTADMIN"
  warehouse = "transforming"
}

resource "snowflake_schema" "schema" {
  database = "database"
  name     = "schema"
  comment  = "A schema."

  is_transient        = false
  is_managed          = false
  data_retention_days = 1
}
```

and the error I get back is

```
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: open snowflake connection: 260008 (08004): failed to connect to db. verify account name is correct. HTTP: 403, URL: https://QC62619.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=ffadd7f9-e260-42bf-4280-a217512bafda&request_guid=c99ae309-17da-4762-7dd2-3839690f290c&roleName=ACCOUNTADMIN&warehouse=transforming
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/snowflake-labs/snowflake"],
│   on main.tf line 10, in provider "snowflake":
│   10: provider "snowflake" {
```

A few things to note:

1. I am specifying account `yzazxrk-pj50733` but the error refers to account `QC62619`;
2. My account details are below;
3. I have tried the following as accounts: `yzazxrk-pj50733`, `yzazxrk`, `QC62619`, `QC62619.europe-west2.gcp` ([based on Account Locator docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier#using-an-account-locator-as-an-identifier))
4. The URL I use to sign in on the browser is https://yzazxrk-pj50733.snowflakecomputing.com but https://qc62619.europe-west2.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com/ also works.

I have read other similar questions here and in the Snowflake community but none has solved the issue.

[image: Snowflake Account details]

Comment: It should be whatever you get when you hit the Copy icon in the screenshot you've provided

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying your account using environment variables

```bash
export SNOWFLAKE_USER="user"
export SNOWFLAKE_AUTHENTICATOR=JWT
export SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY=`cat ~/.ssh/<your_snowflake_key_here>.p8`
export SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT="yzazxrk-pj50733"
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct value for [account identifier](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Snowflake-Labs/snowflake/latest/docs#optional) is `{organization}-{account}`

Double check in Snowflake your account info:

```sql
SELECT
    LOWER(CONCAT_WS(
    '-',
    CURRENT_ORGANIZATION_NAME(),
    CURRENT_ACCOUNT_NAME()
)) AS account_identifier
;
```

Next step I would suggest is checking your `user` and `password` for typos. If still an error, check your [Network Policy](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/network-policies) if your IP address is allowed to connect.

Also, you don't need to connect with a warehouse in the provider. (If you are trying to use a warehouse not granted to that user, you will not be able to connect.)